# maximum number of consecutive 's in the binary for a given wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, decimal

Whats wrong in my code

```
import sys

x=0
y=[]
n = bin(int(input()))
for i in n:
    if i == 1:
        x +=1
    else:
        y.append(x)
        x=0
y.append(x)
print(max(y))
```

Output

```
5
0b101    
0
```

Expected Output

```
5
0b101
1
```

(Consecutive Ones in the binary for given decimal)

Comment: What is input so far?

Comment: what does consecutive 1's mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
```

You're iterating over a string, so the elements are one-character strings.

```
>>> list(bin(5))
['0', 'b', '1', '0', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to pack the `1`s together.

As @joshlee mentioned, you need to check for string equality :

```
from itertools import groupby

n = bin(int(input()))

print(n)
print(max([len(list(bits)) for bit, bits in groupby(n[2:]) if bit == '1']))
```

With `5` :

```
5
0b101
1
```

And with `31` :

```
31
0b11111
5
```

For once, it's an advantage that `groupby` doesn't sort before grouping. For `13` :

```
13
0b1101
2
```

The result should be `2`, not `3` (the total count of `"1"`s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import sys


n = int(input().strip())
bin_n = "{0:b}".format(n)

count = 0
count_l = []
for each in bin_n:
    if each == '1':
        count+=1
    else:
        count_l.append(count)
        count = 0

print(max(count_l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binary_string = str(bin(int(input())))[2:]
print(max(list(map(len, binary_string.split('0')))))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
  n = int(input())
    binary = bin(n)[2:]

    count = 0
    count_no=[]
    for num in binary:
        if num=='1':
            count += 1
        else:
            count_no.append(count)
            count = 0 
    count_no.append(count)
    print(max(count_no))
```